# What does this question mean (manhattan distance)?

Tags: geometry

Given *N* points in *K* dimensional space, determine the point such that sum of Manhattan distances from this point to the N points is minimized?

Output:
For each testcase, output in a single line containing *K* space separated integers denoting the required point in *K* dimensional space. If there are multiple possible answers, print the lexicographically smallest point.

Constraints
$1≤T≤5$
$2≤N≤10^5$
$1≤K≤5$
All co-ordinates are in the range $[−10^9,10^9]$
Subtasks
30 points : $1≤N≤100$
70 points : original contraints
Sample Input
1
3 3
1 1 1
2 2 2
3 3 3

Sample Output:
2 2 2
EXPLANATION:
The total cost at (2,2,2) is 6 and this is optimal.

How to minimize manhattan distance in k dimentions ?

Comment: Dear Dank, welcome to MSE! Two things: first of all this is not a place where to ask for solving exercises. You are supposed to ask questions if something is not clear or at least provide your attempts if you need hints. Secondly, your problem doesn't seem to fit the MSE content. Please have a look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/help)

Comment: This question has been put on-hold as a cheating attempt - https://www.codechef.com/LOCJUL18/problems/CLPOINT